# Login as root in ubuntu server 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, root, etcpasswd

I have a problem to login as root.
My `'/etc/passwd'` file is like

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:which zsh
....
....
```

I asked similar question at [*"How can I change the shell for to original one (/bin/bash) without root privilege?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32653317/3569208) and I the proposed suggestions, but till now it doesn't work.

```
[]@[]:~$ su - root
Password:
Cannot execute which zsh: No such file or directory
[]@[]:~$ su - -s /bin/bash
Password:
Cannot execute which zsh: No such file or directory
[]@[]:~$ su - -s /bin/bash root
Password:
Cannot execute which zsh: No such file or directory
[]@[]:~$ su -s /bin/bash root
Password:
Cannot execute which zsh: No such file or directory
```

Any suggestions for this situation?

Comment: Could you please add a link to the original question?

Comment: Whatever this other answer suggested to you, please revert it before trying my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command, replacing `/bin/sh` with your preferred shell:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh sudo -s
```

This command first sets the `SHELL` environment variable temporarily to `/bin/sh` or whatever shell you chose. Then it invokes `sudo -s` which logs into the shell defined by the `SHELL` variable.

See the example terminal log. Note the `ps` output which once shows `bash` (my default shell) and once `sh` as second process in the hierarchy, as well as the different prompts.

```
$  sudo -s
root: ~ #  ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
23103 pts/2    00:00:00 sudo
23104 pts/2    00:00:00 bash
23146 pts/2    00:00:00 ps
root: ~ #  exit
ipc-admin: ~ $  SHELL=/bin/sh sudo -s
# ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
23190 pts/2    00:00:00 sudo
23191 pts/2    00:00:00 sh
23200 pts/2    00:00:00 ps
# exit
$
```

Comment: You know, there isn't any user in sudoers file. So I can't do any sudo commands. :(

Comment: Can you please give me the link to your original question then, so that I can understand the original problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the *runlevel* at boot time, and to start with *runlevel 1*.
Then you will be root and you can edit each file.

> If using LILO, access the boot: prompt by typing [Ctrl]-[X]. Then type:

```
linux 1
```

> If using GRUB, follow these steps:
>
> - In the graphical GRUB boot loader screen, select a label and press [e] to edit it.
> - Arrow down to the kernel line and press [e] to edit it.
> - At the prompt, type the number of the runlevel you wish to boot into (1 through 5), or the words single or emergency and press [Enter]. **In your case 1**
> - The GRUB screen reappears with the kernel information. Press the [b] key to boot the system.

When you are in *single user mode*, you are root. Use `vi` (or `nano` or `pico` ...)  and correct your `/etc/passwd` file.

Reference:

- [2.10. Changing Runlevels at Boot Time](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/Reference_Guide/s1-grub-runlevels.html).
- [How-To: Change boot runlevel with Grub2](http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-change-boot-runlevel-with-grub2/)